# Upper bound on expectations of the sum of product of a martingale difference sequence with a predictable sequence, weighted by certain random weights

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, measure-concentration

Let $(\mathcal{F}_i)_{i\geq 1}$ be a filtration. Let $0\leq p_i\leq 1$, be a random variable measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}_i$. Consider two sequences of random vectors $v_i\in\mathbb{R}^M,w_i\in\mathbb{R}^M$, each of which is measurable w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}_i$. Suppose,

$w_1,w_2,\ldots$ forms a martingale difference sequence w.r.t $\mathcal{F}_i$. Hence $\mathbb{E}[w_i|\mathcal{F}_{i-1}]=0$.

For all $i$, each of the components of $w_i$ is bounded in absolute value by $W$,

For all $i$, each of the components of $v_i$ is bounded, in absolute value by 1, and $||v_i||_2\leq \sqrt{2},||v_i||_{1}\leq 2$. (Basically $v_i$ is the difference of two vectors, each belonging to the $M$ dimensional simplex).

Now consider the random variable

$$ Z=\sum_{i=1}^T p_i v_{i-1}^T w_i.$$

How large can $\mathbb{E} Z$ be? It is easy to prove that $\mathbb{E}Z=O(T\sqrt{\ln(M)})$. However is it possible to prove that $\mathbb{E}Z=O(\sqrt{T\ln(M)})$?

P.S. I am somewhat skeptical that the dependence on $T$ can be improved to sublinear in $T$, without making any additional assumptions on how $p_i$ evolves. My intuition says that $p_i$ could be set by an adversary in a "bad" way to make $Z$ very large. However it would be great if I am proven wrong :-)

Comment: try $M=1, p = 1_{w>0}$